# Etimología de «verter»

Tags: etimología

«verter» significa:

> Derramar o vaciar líquidos, y también cosas menudas, como sal, harina, etc

Y según [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/verter) y [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verter#Spanish), se deriva de la palabra «vertere» de Latín.  Pero «vertere» [significa](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verto#Latin) voltar, revertir, cambiar, etc.  Nada de líquidos.

¿Cuál es la etimología de «verter»? Si de hecho se deriva de «vertere», ¿de cuál sentido?

Answer (score 5):

**Verter** deriva del latín **vertere** que significa literalmente "**dar vuelta**". De ahí proviene una lista larga de palabras españolas de significados muy distintos. Como es normal en la historia de las palabras, se ha llegado a esos significados por metáforas y metonimias.

A continuación, en el primer punto, indico el origen de **verter** para responder a tu pregunta. Después agrego otras palabras relacionadas que pueden parecerte interesantes:

- Verter: Por contigüidad de significados (causa y efecto), verter pasó a significar "derramar", porque normalmente al "dar vuelta" un recipiente se derrama su contenido. De esta acepción deriva también la "vertiente" de agua.
- Invertir: Formada con el prefijo *in*, significa literalmente "girar hacia adentro". Pasó a significar *cambiar la dirección de algo en el sentido contrario*. De ahí proviene también el concepto económico "inversión", que implica (o implicaba originalmente) que los bienes "vuelven" a la empresa.
- Versus: Es el participio pasado de vertere, algo así como "dado vuelta". Su uso original en latín era para decir que *algo o alguien está orientado hacia...* Este significado persiste en la palabra "advertir", que significa "enfrentar, dirigir la atención hacia...". La misma raíz está con un sentido negativo en "adverso" ("confrontado"), y por lo tanto en "adversario" y "adversidad". Con el sentido de "confrontación" la palabra pasó al inglés, y de ahí a su uso actual universal.
- Vértebras: los huesos de la columna que le permiten "dar vuelta". De ahí deriva "vertebrados".
- Vértigo: la sensación de que la cabeza te "da vueltas". La palabra ya existía en latín, su relación con *vertere* es anterior.

Que baste con eso, pero hay más: verso, universo, universidad, conversar, reverso, revés, controversia, aniversario, vértice, vertical, diverso, divertido.